# configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables (running on Windows)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, gcc

Hi I working on Windows 7 and am trying to install special RUby Binary to make the full use of ruby-prof on rails 3.2. I am following the steps outlined here https://github.com/rails/rails-perftest/tree/v0.0.4.
When I get to step where I run

```
./configure --prefix=/C:/rubygc
```

I get the following error:

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/C:/rubygc
checking build system type... i686-pc-mingw32
checking host system type... i686-pc-mingw32
checking target system type... i686-pc-mingw32
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/c/ruby-1.9.3-p545':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

By the way and just installed gcc using MinGW installation manager.
The content of the config.log that is mentioned is:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
```

running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by configure, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

$ ./configure --prefix=/C:/rubygc

```
## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = XXX-1KCXTZ1-001
uname -m = i686
uname -r = 1.0.12(0.46/3/2)
uname -s = MINGW32_NT-6.1
uname -v = 2012-07-05 14:56

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /c/Users/issadmin/bin
PATH: .
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /mingw/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /c/Program Files/PHP/v5.3
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/Mozilla Firefox
PATH: /c/Program Files/ImageMagick-6.8.9-Q16
PATH: /c/Ruby193/bin
PATH: /c/Windows/system32
PATH: /c/Windows
PATH: /c/Windows/System32/Wbem
PATH: /c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/ZipGenius 6/
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/Google/Google Apps Sync/
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/QuickTime/QTSystem/
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/Novell/ZENworks/bin
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.1/Windows Performance Toolkit/
PATH: /c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/110/Tools/Binn/
PATH: /c/Program Files/Microsoft/Web Platform Installer/
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft ASP.NET/ASP.NET Web Pages/v1.0/
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/bin
PATH: /usr/cmd
PATH: /usr/cmd
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/Google/google_appengine/
PATH: /c/Python27/
PATH: /c/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin
PATH: /c/MinGW/bin
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/Google/google_appengine/
PATH: /c/Python27/
PATH:  


## ----------- ##

## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2800: checking build system type
configure:2814: result: i686-pc-mingw32
configure:2882: checking host system type
configure:2895: result: i686-pc-mingw32
configure:2915: checking target system type
configure:2928: result: i686-pc-mingw32
configure:3153: checking for gcc
configure:3169: found /c/MinGW/bin/gcc
configure:3180: result: gcc

configure:3409: checking for C compiler version
configure:3418: gcc --version >&5
gcc.exe (GCC) 4.8.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:3429: $? = 0
configure:3418: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=c:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-4.8.1/configure --prefix=/mingw --host=mingw32 --build=mingw32 --without-pic --enable-shared --enable-static --with-gnu-ld --enable-lto --enable-libssp --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++,ada --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-dwarf2 --disable-win32-registry --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-gmp=/usr/src/pkg/gmp-5.1.2-1-mingw32-src/bld --with-mpc=/usr/src/pkg/mpc-1.0.1-1-mingw32-src/bld --with-mpfr= --with-system-zlib --with-gnu-as --enable-decimal-float=yes --enable-libgomp --enable-threads --with-libiconv-prefix=/mingw32 --with-libintl-prefix=/mingw --disable-bootstrap LDFLAGS=-s CFLAGS=-D_USE_32BIT_TIME_T
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.8.1 (GCC) 
configure:3429: $? = 0
configure:3418: gcc -V >&5
gcc.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3429: $? = 1
configure:3418: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'
gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3429: $? = 1
configure:3449: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3471: gcc    conftest.c  >&5
configure:3475: $? = 0
configure:3513: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define CANONICALIZATION_FOR_MATHN 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3518: error: in `/c/ruby-1.9.3-p545':
configure:3520: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=i686-pc-mingw32
ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_host=i686-pc-mingw32
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=gcc
ac_cv_target=i686-pc-mingw32

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ALLOCA=''
AR=''
ARCHFILE=''
ARCH_FLAG=''
AS=''
ASFLAGS=''
BASERUBY='ruby'
BUILTIN_ENCOBJS=''
BUILTIN_TRANSOBJS=''
BUILTIN_TRANSSRCS=''
CAPITARGET=''
CC='gcc'
CCDLFLAGS=''
CFLAGS=''
CHDIR=''
COMMON_HEADERS=''
COMMON_LIBS=''
COMMON_MACROS=''
COUTFLAG=''
CP=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CPPOUTFILE=''
CXX=''
CXXFLAGS=''
DEFS=''
DLDFLAGS=''
DLDLIBS=''
DLEXT2=''
DLEXT=''
DLLWRAP=''
DOT=''
DOXYGEN=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
ENABLE_SHARED=''
EXECUTABLE_EXTS=''
EXEEXT=''
EXPORT_PREFIX=''
EXTDLDFLAGS=''
EXTOUT=''
EXTSTATIC=''
GCC=''
GNU_LD=''
GREP=''
INSTALLDOC=''
INSTALL_DATA=''
INSTALL_PROGRAM=''
INSTALL_SCRIPT=''
LDFLAGS=''
LDSHARED=''
LDSHAREDXX=''
LIBEXT=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBPATHENV=''
LIBPATHFLAG=''
LIBRUBY=''
LIBRUBYARG=''
LIBRUBYARG_SHARED=''
LIBRUBYARG_STATIC=''
LIBRUBY_A=''
LIBRUBY_ALIASES=''
LIBRUBY_DLDFLAGS=''
LIBRUBY_LDSHARED=''
LIBRUBY_RELATIVE=''
LIBRUBY_SO=''
LIBS=''
LINK_SO=''
LN_S=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAINLIBS=''
MAJOR='1'
MAKEDIRS=''
MAKEFILES=''
MANTYPE=''
MINIOBJS=''
MINIRUBY=''
MINOR='9'
MKDIR_P=''
NM=''
NROFF=''
NULLCMD=''
OBJCOPY=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJEXT=''
OUTFLAG=''
PACKAGE=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME=''
PACKAGE_STRING=''
PACKAGE_TARNAME=''
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION=''
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PKG_CONFIG=''
PLATFORM_DIR=''
POSTLINK=''
PREP=''
RANLIB=''
RDOCTARGET=''
RI_BASE_NAME=''
RM=''
RMALL=''
RMDIR=''
RMDIRS=''
RPATHFLAG=''
RUBYW_BASE_NAME='rubyw'
RUBYW_INSTALL_NAME=''
RUBY_BASE_NAME='ruby'
RUBY_INSTALL_NAME=''
RUBY_PROGRAM_VERSION='1.9.3'
RUBY_RELEASE_DATE='2014-02-24'
RUBY_SO_NAME=''
RUNRUBY=''
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/sh'
SOLIBS=''
STATIC=''
STRIP=''
SYMBOL_PREFIX=''
TEENY='1'
TEST_RUNNABLE=''
THREAD_MODEL=''
TRY_LINK=''
UNIVERSAL_ARCHNAMES=''
UNIVERSAL_INTS=''
USE_RUBYGEMS=''
WERRORFLAG=''
WINDRES=''
XCFLAGS=''
XLDFLAGS=''
XRUBY=''
XRUBY_LIBDIR=''
XRUBY_RUBYHDRDIR=''
XRUBY_RUBYLIBDIR=''
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
ac_ct_CXX=''
ac_ct_OBJCOPY=''
ac_ct_OBJDUMP=''
arch=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='i686-pc-mingw32'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='i686'
build_os='mingw32'
build_vendor='pc'
cflags=' ${optflags} ${debugflags} ${warnflags}'
codesign=''
configure_args=''
cppflags=''
cxxflags=' ${optflags} ${debugflags} ${warnflags}'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
debugflags=''
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec=''
exec_prefix='NONE'
host='i686-pc-mingw32'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='i686'
host_os='mingw32'
host_vendor='pc'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
optflags=''
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='/C:/rubygc'
program_transform_name='s&^&&'
psdir='${docdir}'
ridir=''
ruby_pc=''
ruby_version=''
rubyhdrdir=''
rubylibprefix=''
rubyw_install_name=''
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
setup=''
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sitearch=''
sitedir=''
sitehdrdir=''
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target='i686-pc-mingw32'
target_alias=''
target_cpu='i686'
target_os='mingw32'
target_vendor='pc'
try_header=''
vendordir=''
vendorhdrdir=''
warnflags=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME ""
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
#define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
#define PACKAGE_STRING ""
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_URL ""
#define CANONICALIZATION_FOR_MATHN 1

configure: exit 77
```

Comment: Are you able to compile a 'Hello World!' program with the MinGW compiler? (Search: mingw hello world example)